# Grouping Java 8. Inner grouping based on time interval from a given start time

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I've the list in the following format:

```
int intervalInMinutes = 10;
String startTimeForGrouping = "2017-05-09T15:37:51.896+00:00";
List<MyObject> myObjList = Arrays.asList( 
    new MyObject("1","a","2017-05-09T15:38:51.896+00:00"),
    new MyObject("1","a","2017-05-09T16:41:51.896+00:00"),
    new MyObject("1","a","2017-05-09T16:49:51.896+00:00"),
    new MyObject("1","a","2017-05-09T16:51:51.896+00:00"),
    new MyObject("2","b","2017-05-09T17:38:51.896+00:00"),
    new MyObject("2","b","2017-05-09T18:41:51.896+00:00")
);
```

I've got the list in the above format:
I wanted to iterate through that and perform some grouping with an interval from given start time and achieve as follows:
In the above list, the group id 1 should return 2 lists.

First 2 objects in the single list because its in the first interval from startTimeForGrouping ("2017-05-09T15:37:51.896+00:00" + intervalInMinutes (10)).

3rd and 4th in a different list because that comes in the next interval ("2017-05-09T15:47:51.896+00:00" + intervalInMinutes (10)). The same logic should repeat for id 2 as well

I have tried this

```
Map<String, Map<Long, List<MyObject>>> aggrResult =
myObjList.stream()
    .collect(
        Collectors.groupingBy(
            MyObject::getId,
            Collectors.groupingBy(eachQueueObj -> eachQueueObj.getIntervalStartTime()/interval)));
```

but this is wrong because I want to aggregate based on the interval from the given start time.

Please help me since am new to java streaming

Comment: What do you expect the inner map's keys to be?

Comment: thanks . the first inner key should be the starting interval ((startTimeForGrouping + intervalInMinutes)) and next one should be (startTimeForGrouping + intervalInMinutes +intervalInMinutes) for a given id

Comment: for the nested grouping you can group by `(eachQueueObj.getIntervalStartTime() - startTimeForGrouping)/interval`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should parse the date strings into `Instant` objects, and call `Duration.between` to get a duration. Then, divide that duration by `intervalInMinutes` minutes. Finally, multiply this number by `intervalInMinutes` and add that to `startTimeForGrouping` to get the grouping key.

Before the stream operation, parse `startTimeForGrouping` to an instant, and make a `Duration` from `startTimeForGrouping`:

```
Instant startInstant = OffsetDateTime.parse(startTimeForGrouping).toInstant();
Duration interval = Duration.ofMinutes(startTimeForGrouping);
```

Then you can declare a method `roundInstant`:

```
public static Instant roundInstant(Instant instant, Duration interval, Instant start) {
    long multiple =
            Duration.between(start, instant)
                .getSeconds() / interval.getSeconds();
    return start.plus(interval.multipliedBy(multiple));
}
```

The second `groupingBy` call can then look like this:

```
Collectors.groupingBy(
    eachQueueObj -> roundInstant(
        OffsetDateTime.parse(eachQueueObj.getIntervalStartTime()).toInstant(),
        interval,
        startInstant
    ).getEpochSecond()
)
```

In fact, I would recommend you to *not* use `String`s and `Long`s, and work with `Instant`s directly.

Comment: I would encourage to move that logic to a method, such that it is cleaner and reusable, then invoke the method in `groupingBy`. That is also the actual problem statement in the question.

Answer (score 1):

I think the code is that,you could try and remodify the getTime method to fix your need

```
 package com.test;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

/**
 *
 *
 *
 *
 *
 *
 * @author shikai.liu
 * @version 1.0
 * @since JDK1.7
 */
public class TestList {

    public static String strDateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX";
    public static SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(strDateFormat);

    public static class MyObject {
        public String id;
        public String code;
        public String time;

        public MyObject(String id, String code, String time) {
            this.code = code;
            this.id = id;
            this.time = time;
        }

        public String getId() {
            return this.id;
        }

        public String getIntervalStartTime() {
            return time;
        }

        public long getTime(Integer t, String srcTime) {
            long result = 0;
            try {

                Date dstDate = sdf.parse(time);
                Date srcDate = sdf.parse(srcTime);
                long inteval = dstDate.getTime() - srcDate.getTime();

                result = inteval / (1000 * 60) / t;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return result;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int intervalInMinutes = 10;
        String startTimeForGrouping = "2017-05-09T15:37:51.896+00:00";
        List<MyObject> myObjList = Arrays.asList(new MyObject("1", "a", "2017-05-09T15:38:51.896+00:00"), new MyObject("1", "a",
                "2017-05-09T16:41:51.896+00:00"), new MyObject("1", "a", "2017-05-09T16:49:51.896+00:00"), new MyObject("1", "a",
                "2017-05-09T16:51:51.896+00:00"), new MyObject("2", "b", "2017-05-09T17:38:51.896+00:00"), new MyObject("2", "b",
                "2017-05-09T18:41:51.896+00:00"));

        Map<String, Map<Long, List<MyObject>>> aggrResult = myObjList.stream().collect(
                Collectors.groupingBy(MyObject::getId, Collectors.groupingBy(a -> a.getTime(intervalInMinutes, startTimeForGrouping))));
        System.out.println(1);
    }
}
```